# Calculate how many chararcters can fit on one line of a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, string, character, word-wrap

I'm trying to stop text from wrapping when it doesnt fit in a line of a multi-line (numberOfLines = 0) label but to do that I need to know how many characters can fit in a line of the label so I can cut off the rest and just use "\n" to add the next string to the next line. How would I go about finding how many characters can fit on each line with my font and size and size of the label (Courier 17.0 monospaced by the way). Also the size of the label can be dynamic since like screen size/size classes can change, which is why this is needed.

Ex of what I want to happen and why I need to know how many characters fit
on a line:

```
var lineOne = "Too long"
var lineTwo = "Also too long"
myLabel.text = lineOne + "\n" + lineTwo
// Then I would calculate how many characters can fit on a line and alter the two strings accordingly
```

Output of the label (pretend the label character limit happens to be like 3):

```
Too
Als
```

I Just realized another thing I need to be able to calculate is how many lines can fit in a label (height) if the numberOfLines = 0.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to do them programmatically..
To do that, Select your label and in the Attributes inspector, change the 
 `Line Break` to `Character Wrap`.
Then change `Lines` to the maximum amount of lines you want to allow.

And you can add constraints for height and width accordingly. Then use `<labelOutlet>.sizeToFit();`

Comment: This doesnt solve the problem of knowing where to cut each string so it fills the line. Because with this method the if I dont add \n the lines clump and still wrap